# Gaps in walls Cura

Tags: ultimaker-cura

I'm new to the 3D printing world and I'm using the default options of Ultimaker Cura to slice and print a couple of cookie cutters.

I have a model that looks alright, but when I slice it, some walls are missing for the Preview object.

Here you can see how the model looks pre and post-slicing.

[image]

[image]

Can you help me with this? Do you know what I have to do to avoid these gaps in my sliced object?

I have a Artillery Sidewinder X2 which I use together with Ultimaker Cura. I print in PLA at 200 °C. The print bed is set to 60 °C. The layer height I set to 0.2 mm, the line width [0.44 mm] from the nozzle. The Printing Speed is set to 25 mm/s for walls and 50 mm/s for infill. My retraction is 3 mm

Comment: What Cura version?

Comment: Ultimaker Cura 5.2.2

Comment: And how thin are the features that are getting lost when slicing?

Comment: Can you share this model file, that you are trying to print?